# Python dataframe to json with "variable name:" and "value:"

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert a dataframe lets say:

| id | age | phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | 30012345 |
| 2 | 30 | 12233456 |

to a Json file with this format:

```html
{{ "name":"id",
  "value":"1" },
{ "name":"age",
  "value":"20" },
{ "name":"phone",
  "value":"30012345" }},
{{ "name":"id",
  "value":"2" },
{ "name":"age",
  "value":"30" },
{ "name":"phone",
  "value":"12233456" }}
```

any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: do you think the data inside JSON file you want is correct?

Comment: Yup, is an API requierement

Comment: Shouldn't that be a list of jsons ? With the first symbol being a bracket `[`? In which case you'd have to give it a `key` to be able to put it inside a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :

```
json_dict = {}
dict_convert = df.to_dict('record')
for row_info in dict_convert:
    pre_dict = {}
    for key, val in row_info.items():
        pre_dict.update({'name': key,'value':val})
    json_dict.update(pre_dict)
    del pre_dict
# now you have the format you can dump it
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(json_dict, fp)
```

Comment: I feel I'm close but I'm just getting this {'name': 'co_smb_ab_testing', 'value': nan} (which is just the last variable with the last record)

Comment: ok , i see, I will fixed in in min